# igraph: tree graph where terminal (not root) nodes are at same level?

Tags: r, graph, igraph, network-analysis

I would like to plot a tree graph with `igraph` in R, having all the terminal nodes at the same level, unlike the default where all root nodes are at the same level.

`layout_as_tree` has a way to do this, based on the root nodes. One needs to specify them (`root`), as well as their level (`rootlevel`). So I could use this option, though it seem it would involve a very complicated workflow of a) splitting my tree into subtrees b) finding the root node of each subtree c) finding the largest path of each subtree 4) specifying root first level relative to others...

Is there a simpler way to do so by starting from the terminal nodes? Say I don't know which nodes are the root ones (1 and 11), but only know which ones are the terminal ones (4:11 and 16:20).

Here is an example, but I would like terminal nodes 4, 16 and 17 to be at the lowest level:

```r
library(igraph)
tree2 <- make_tree(10, 3) + make_tree(10, 2)

plot(tree2, layout=layout_as_tree(tree2, root=c(1,11),
                                  rootlevel=c(2, 1)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When counting the level from bottom to top, the solution becomes:

```
require(igraph)

tree2  <- make_tree(10, 3) + make_tree(10, 2) + edge(1,5)
tree3  <- set_edge_attr(tree2, name="weight", value=-1) # longest path = shortest negative.
dist   <- (-distances(tree3, v=(V(tree3)), mode="out")) # matrix of VxV distances of shortest paths.
layers <- apply(dist, 1, max)                           # maximum distance from bottom to top (max per row).
layers <- max(layers) - layers                          # minimal distance from top    to bottom.

plot(tree3, layout=layout_with_sugiyama(tree3, layers=layers))
```

If the `dist` matrix does not fit in memory then a `dfs()` search must be done, calculating the layers.

Comment: this is the one! thanks a lot for all the answers you posted

Comment: looking at the code some time after, I'm confused about the line `set_edge_attr(tree2, name="weight", value=-1)`... what is its purpose? Is the `weight` attribute used after in the computations? Thanks!

Comment: Add an edge between vertices 1, 5: `tree2  <- make_tree(10, 3) + make_tree(10, 2) + edge(c(1,5))`.  The purpose of the statement is to assign level = 3 to vertex 5, rather 1.

Answer (score 1):

In the example supplied, calculate roots and rootlevels as follows:

```
require(igraph) 
tree2 <- make_tree(10, 3) + make_tree(10, 2)

roots <- V(tree2)[which(degree(tree2, mode="in") == 0)]   # no incoming edges
dist      <- distances(tree2, roots)                      # all distances from roots
dist[which(is.infinite(dist))] <- NA                      # remove infinite
rootlevel  <- apply(dist, 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)           # max per row
rootlevel  <- max(rootlevel) - rootlevel + 1              # offset
plot(tree2, layout=layout_as_tree(tree2, root=roots, rootlevel=rootlevel))
```

If the `dist` matrix does not fit in memory then a `dfs()` search must be done, calculating the layers.

Comment: thanks clp! My bad, I realize the plot example I gave was bad: 4, 16 and 17 should be at the lowest level, given that they are terminal nodes (edited). It seems actually that the answer with `layout_with_sugiyama` that you initially shared was solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a more basic approach.
In this solution, we search the graph via a `depth-first search` and recursively compute the layers of each vertex.

```
require(igraph)
tree2  <- make_tree(10, 3) + make_tree(10, 2)

## Depth-first search.
## Mark node as visited.
## Calculate layers indexed by vertex.
## Layer of v is
##   - equal to zero if there are no descendants and
##   - otherwise the largest layer among the descendants plus 1.
layers <- rep(0L, vcount(tree2))
visit <- function(g, v){
  if (length(visited)>0L && !visited[v]) {
    visited[v] <<- 1L

    max_layer_descendents <- -1L 
    outgoing <- V(g)[.outnei(v)]
    for (w in outgoing) {
      stopifnot(v != w)
      visit(g, w)
      max_layer_descendents <- max(max_layer_descendents, layers[w])
    }

    layers[v] <<- max_layer_descendents + 1L
  }
}

## mark vertices as non-visited and calculate layers
visited <- rep(0L, vcount(tree2))
for (v in V(tree2)) visit(tree2, v)
layers
# [1] 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 2 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0

plot(tree2, layout=layout_with_sugiyama(tree2, layers=max(layers)-layers))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, but at the cost of inverting all edges:

```
require(igraph)
tree2  <- make_tree(10, 3) + make_tree(10, 2)

## Calculate x,y coordinates by Sugiyama,
## flip y coordinate, and plot.
lyt     <- layout_with_sugiyama(reverse_edges(tree2))$layout
lyt[,2] <- (1L + max(lyt[,2])) - lyt[,2]
lyt[,2]
plot(tree2, layout=lyt)
```

which gives

```
[1] 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 3 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
```