# Is there an R function to find the nodes of a DAG at a certain depth in R?

Tags: r, igraph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am a new user of the igraph package in R. I want to extract a list of the nodes of a DAG at a certain depth. The nodes at a particular depth do not have a common edge. Could someone help with what is the best code to do so? I looked into the ego() and neighbors() functions from igraph package, but, neither these or there does not seem to be an in-built function that simply enlists the member nodes at a certain depth. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Also I tried the dfs and bfs search, but I couldn't use these functions to solve my question either.

Comment: you should elaborate your question with a code example as well as the desired output, then others can help.

Comment: Look more carefully at `ego` (also called `neighborhood`): it has an `order` and a `mindist` parameter. Use the two in conjunction.

Comment: But as Thomas says, the question could use some clarification. What is "a certain depth"?  Are you assuming a single zero-indegree source vertex? What if there are multiple?

Answer (score 0):

Assume:

- level is grouped by the length of the shorttest path from a bottom vertex.
- indexed from top to bottom.
- bottom vertex does not have any outgoing edges.

```
    library(igraph)
    
    ## create some DAG.
    g <- graph_from_literal(a -+ b:c:d:e, b -+ d, c -+ d:e, d -+ e)
    g <- set_edge_attr(g, name="weight", value=-1)          # longest path = shortest negative.
    dist   <- (-distances(g, v=(V(g)), mode="out"))         # matrix of VxV distances of shortest paths.
    layers <- apply(dist, 1, max)                           # maximum distance from bottom to top (max per row).
    layers <- max(layers) - layers                          # minimal distance from top    to bottom.
    
    plot(g, layout=layout_with_sugiyama(g, layers=layers))  # show the graph by level.
      
    d = 1                                                   # certain depth d. 
    layers[which(layers==d)]
    ## b c 
    ## 1 1
```

For a more elaborate answer, see: [igraph: tree graph where terminal (not root) nodes are at same level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73828475/igraph-tree-graph-where-terminal-not-root-nodes-are-at-same-level/73843947#73843947)